# Getting attachments from Microsoft Graph returns wrong size

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-mail

Using the .NET SDK for Microsoft Graph API to fetch Attachments on an event, returns Attachments where the size property doesn't match the size of the attachment content length.

For instance using this code snippet (using the .NET SDK)

```
var attachments = await graphServiceClient
    .Me
    .Events[id]
    .Attachments
    .Request()
    .GetAsync();
```

returns a FileAttachment object where the ContentBytes property has a length of 34877 and the Size property is 35137.

The content of the attachment is correct, it is just the Size property that, seems to be off

Comment: I'm dealing with the same problem as you, it took me a lot of time.

Answer (score 0):

It’s because the content is gzip’ed